# Z-index and stacking

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to figure out out to create a event to appear in front of my home without it opening a new page. It would, for lack of a better word, expand to fill the browser. I know I'll have to do some work with z-index and javascript. The month would hover and then the user would click to see the event.

[Home and event](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Epp7G.png)

My HTML

```
<div class= "month sep_box">
    <h1 class= "sep">SEP</h1>
    <div class= "year">2016</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.sep_box{
    background-image: url("images/design_disrupt.svg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background-position: center;
    float: left;
    width: 25%;
    height: 25vh;
    transition:.25s ease;
}
```

EDIT: Screen-shoted HTML now copied

```
    <article> 
<div><h1 id="design_disruptors">
    DESIGN <br />DISRUPTORS</h1></div>
    <div><p class="child_day">THURSDAY</p></div>
    <div><p class="child_day_number">15</p></div>
    <div><p class="child_event_about">JCM 2121<br />7:00pm</p></div>
    <div><p class="child_rsvp">RSVP</p></div>
    <div><p class="child_desc">Design Disruptors reveals<br /> 
                               a never-before-seen<br /> 
                               perspective on the design approaches of these<br /> 
                               companies and how they<br />
                               are overtaking billion dollar industries though design.</p>
</div>
</article>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/es60r7cv/

Comment: So: before we answer this question technically, are you sure about this UI?  Because, if you want to simply hover the month and get the event details in an overlay, how would one ever get the event details for, say, August? There's no clean path to get the mouse over that month square without passing over some other month, which will pop up an even detail that covers the whole screen?

Comment: is it called modal? http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_modal.asp

Comment: @anied Sorry if I didn't clarify. The hover wouldn't make it pop. The click will .The hover is simply to prompt a click. The user would click the home in the top left to exit the details of an event. To your particular question, no events occur in June through August and December. The tricky thing is that I'm completely new to code (first semester Interactive) so I'm trying to figure out how to ask for advice.

Comment: Gotcha.  Well, I agree with "Learn How To Be Transparent" that you are doing a sort of variant of a modal.  If you want to go the easy route, you could definitely leverage [Bootstrap modal solution](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) in order to achieve something similar, but it won't be particularly customizable.  If you want to implement exactly this, the solution will be much more involved-- if you feel up to the challenge, I can provide some more details.

Comment: z-index needs a position rule to work

Comment: @anied here's what my professor said about it. I can sort of grasp it. "I think your hovers/months would be an onclick="toggle-visibility('id')" with the events being absolute articles (each with its own id) with high z-indexes. The absolute article (event) would be a width:100%, high z-index, and would serve as a container for all of your event content. At least, that's how I think it'll work. The problem I see arising is that you have absolute divs within the event container itself. Whatever overlaps the background images you are using. That might pose a problem.

Comment: @anied as apprehensive as I am. I think I'll take on the challenge.

Comment: OK, if we are going to move forward on this, it'll be helpful if you can paste your screenshot HTML into the StackOverflow-- even better if you can get a working jsfiddle -- even if it is broken.  At a glance the screenshot HTML looks like it could use some better tabbing to make it more readable-- I think I see at least one mistake in it, but it could just be unclear because the tabbing is all over the place.  Finally-- what is the intended "hover over" content?  I see images in the screenshot, text in the markup, and an SVG background?

Comment: @anied managed to paste it. I'll look into that. The hover is simply a duplicate of that image but with color on it. The only difference in the code for the hover compared to the .sep_box is .sep_box:hover.

Comment: @A_D - so, I see 7 open <div> tags and only 2 </div> tags.  So obviously something is wrong there.  Keeping your tabs orderly and neat will help you avoid issues like this.  Also, I'm still not completely clear on the behavior you are looking for.  The screen on the left is the normal view, correct?  And then when you click it, it should appear as the view on the right, which is almost completely different save for the clicked square still remains?

Comment: @aneid oops, I forgot to put those </div> tags at the end there. However it still works in preview, I'll put them there anyway to make it correct. Yes you are correct. The clicked square will remain. I suppose the best way to explain it is that the event expands off of the month square BUT it doesn't have to look like it expands. I think the closest to what I'm talking about is this. http://www.ortizleon.es/

Comment: @anied code cleaned up and jsfiddle added.

Answer (score 0):

The comments aren't going to work at this point because of the character limit, so I'm going to try my best to give you some hints here.  I am a little unsure as to how far along you are in your development to this point, and the intent of the design, but let's give it a shot.

Firstly, if I understand your design image correctly, you want almost the entire screen to look different except for the square that was clicked.  This is going to be difficult, as you'll need to position a lot of elements in *just* such a way that you can have a transparency in *exactly* the right spot.  Given your design, and how important pixel-perfection is going to be to making it work, and where you are in your development, I'm wondering if it would be ideal to simply fix the width of the whole design (no growing or shrinking with the screen).

I would also recommend you use [jQuery](https://jquery.com/) for this project, as it will be easier for you.

To add an event listener to all your month boxes using jQuery, you would write it:

```
$(document).on('click', '.month', function (evt) {
    // your event handling code here
}
```

I would give each month element an id for the month it represented, then create your overlays with a similar id.  So, for example, the December month box would be `<div class="month" id="december"><!--your_content--></div>` and the overlay for the month could be `<div class="overlay" id="decemberOverlay"><!--your_overlay_content--></div>`.  That way you could target it by getting the clicked month boxes id, and getting the overlay by doing that id + "Overlay".

You *could* fetch your overlay content on the fly using AJAX, but to reduce complexity for yourself you may just always load all overlays to the page and hide them with CSS, but also include the positioning code:

```
.overlay {
    display: none;
    z-index: 10;
    position: absolute; /* this will position it to the document, or the first parent that is relatively or absolutely positioned */
    top: 0;
    left: 0
}
```

We are using absolute positioning because:

- we want to be able to position the overlay directly over the original image, and not influence the flow of the rest of the document, and
- z-index requires some non-static `position` value to be applied

Then, in your script, you would update it do be this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.month', function (evt) {
    var clickedMonth = this.id;
    var correspondingOverlay = $(clickedMonth+"Overlay");
    correspondingOverlay.show();
}
```

Based on your fiddle and code, I think perhaps you are not very far along yet.  Hopefully this gives you a bit of a head start on how to achieve your desired result.

Edit:
One last thing-- this is a cleaner way to style your markup:

```
<article> 
    <div>
        <h1 id="design_disruptors">DESIGN <br />DISRUPTORS</h1>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="child_day">THURSDAY</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="child_day_number">15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="child_event_about">JCM 2121<br />7:00pm</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="child_rsvp">RSVP</p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p class="child_desc">
            Design Disruptors reveals<br /> 
            a never-before-seen<br /> 
            perspective on the design approaches of these<br /> 
            companies and how they<br />
            are overtaking billion dollar industries though design.
        </p>
    </div>
</article>
```

Clean HTML will be easier to read and easier to spot errors.

Comment: For the event listener code, would the '// your event handling code here' code be my event code from html or css? I don't know what that'd be referring to. What's the overlay? My hovers? Would the <!--your_content--> portion be my the h1 and h2 in my html for that month? Also, is that overlay for when I'm on the home page and it hovers? Or is it for when the event is pulled up?

Comment: @A_D - if you look a little lower in the answer, you'll see that I fill out the event handler for you.  Unfortunately, I believe you may be a bit out if your depth-- S.O. isn't a place where code is written for you-- it's for answering specific questions. You have a jpg with unclear requirements and not much completed code. My apologies- from your question I thought you had more of a development background. I hope I haven't wasted your time. I think you should consider hiring a developer, or doing some tutorials, taking a class or hiring a terror, or checking out SquareSpace even. Good luck!

Comment: I assume the event handler is the clean HTML? I'm in an Interactive 1 class which means I'm new to code. Since I'm new to it, much of the language used is unfamiliar to me so I need it simplified which is hard for those who try to help out. Unfortunately none of the tutorials so far tackle what I'm trying to do. I don't think I can achieve what I hope to. I think just creating a new page would be easiest. Lastly, what jpg are you referring to?

Comment: The event handler is the third code block I included that contains JavaScript code. The jpg I'm referring to is the image you linked [here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Epp7G.png) (It was a png, my mistake). What you want to build is achievable, and I commend you for aiming high-- but I think it may be a bit complex for someone that is completely new to code. Perhaps it will be a more appropriate project in a few months after a few more classes. Good luck with your programming education, and don't get discouraged-- we must learn to walk before we can run!